# Exchanging Object between client and server using sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I am trying to build an application where the server is a bank and the clients are the bracnhs of that bank so it's classic Multithread server / client app. In the first step i want the bank to record every branch that connects to it. so iwant to send the branck as object in the objectstream of the socket so that the bank can extract it and record it.

here's what i have done so far

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;


public class Banque {
private List<Succursale> listSucc = new ArrayList<Succursale>();
private int sommeTotale;
private int nbSuccInit = 4;

public void ajouteSucc(Succursale suc){

}
public Banque(){
    initialiserServeur();       
}
private void initialiserServeur() {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null; 
    try { 
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(10118); 
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    { 
        System.err.println("On ne peut pas ecouter au  port: 10118."); 
        System.exit(1); 
    }
    System.out.println ("Le serveur est en marche, Attente de la connexion.....");
    int i = 0;
    while(i<5){
        try {
            UtilMultiTh mt = new UtilMultiTh(serverSocket.accept());
            Thread t = new Thread(mt);
            t.start();
            listSucc.add(mt.getSuc());
            System.out.println(listSucc.size());

            for(int j =0; j<listSucc.size();j++){
                System.out.println("La succursale "+(j+1)+" est:"+listSucc.get(j).getName());
            }
            i++;
            System.out.println("FLAGPOSTban");
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        { 
            System.err.println("Accept a echoue."); 
            System.exit(1); 
        } 
    }


    System.out.println ("connexion reussie");
    System.out.println ("Attente de l'entree.....");

}
public static void main (String [] args){
    Banque banK = new Banque();
}
```

}

The class MultiTh that manage the multi thread connection of the branchs

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.*;

public class UtilMultiTh implements Runnable {

private Socket soc;
private Succursale suc;
public UtilMultiTh(Socket s){
    System.out.println("FLAGconsmth");
    this.soc = s;
    }
public void run() {
    System.out.println("FLAGPOSrun");
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    ObjectInputStream ois;
    try{            
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());

        //System.out.println("La succ est");
        try {
            Object o = ois.readObject();
            if(o!=null){
                suc = (Succursale)o;
                //System.out.println("La succ est"+suc.getName());
            }
            /*while(o!=null){
                suc = (Succursale)o;
                System.out.println("La succ est"+suc.getName());
            }*/
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        oos.close();
        ois.close();
        soc.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
public synchronized Succursale getSuc() {
    return suc;
}
public void setSuc(Succursale suc) {
    this.suc = suc;
}

}
```

And here's the Succursale class for the branchs

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Succursale implements Serializable {
private String coordonnees;
private String name;
private int sommeDepart;
private int sommeRecue;
private int sommeEnvoyee;
private List<Succursale> listSuccAc = new ArrayList<Succursale>();
private GuiSuccursale succView;

public Succursale (){
    succView = new GuiSuccursale(Constantes.sommeDepart,1);
    this.sommeDepart=Constantes.sommeDepart;
    this.name="Succursale: "+(1);
    connexionBanque();
}
public void connexionBanque(){
    String host = Constantes.adrBanque[0];
    int port = Constantes.portBanque[0];
    Socket echoSocket = null;
    try {
        echoSocket = new Socket(host, port);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(echoSocket.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeObject(this);
        System.out.println("FLAGPOSTSUcc");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Hôte inconnu: " + host);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Ne pas se connecter au serveur: " + host);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
public void connexionSuccursales(){

}
public void envoiManuel(){

}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void envoiPeriodique(){

}
public static void main (String[] args){
    Succursale suc = new Succursale();
}
}
```

I have two questions, how can i from the UtilMultuTh return a Succursale to Banque and before that why is that in the UtilMultiTh class readObject return null while in the succursale class just after etablishing the connection i put the class in the socket ? Do i have to put an infinite loop in here ?

EDIT: I changed the code, now  multith is correctly getting the Succursale from the socket, the problem now is that the threads are no synchronised because UtilMultiTh gets the Succursale after Banque wants to get it, i am not familiar with synchrnosation, how can i tell Banque to do the getSuccursale only after utilMultiTh performed its run ?

Comment: In my opinion, java's serialization is terrible, and sends way to much over the wire, so I would do my own custom marshaling of objects onto the wire, and do my own unmarshaling off of the wire. This way, you know exactly what is being sent across, and you don't have to use object streams.

Comment: @publ1c_stat1c JSON is very compact IMO. We saw an 80% reduction in I/O time when we switched from Java serialization to JSON using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). That made our client waaay more responsive.

Comment: It is pointless to test the result of `readObject()` for null, unless you are planning on sending nulls to yourself for some reason. The method doesn't return null otherwise. If you're using that as an EOS test you are incorrect: you should be catching `EOFException` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Google's protobufs are perfect for this.  I'd suggest using them and sending the byte output between client and server.  You'll need to frame your output if you're planning to use TCP.

Java's serialization mechanism could always break between different runtime versions.  Also, what if you decide to implement the server or client in another language?  You'll have to duplicate java's entire serialization logic.  Protobuf takes care of the tedious process required to marshall and unmarshall objects to and from bytes.  So pretty much, its a better form of java's built in serialization which is language independent.

So I suggest you abandon Object streams.  I know this isn't the answer you were hoping for, but it will make things nicer for you in the long run.

[ProtoBuffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)

Comment: As I said, ProtoBuffers is language independent.  It works with Java, and is a good alternative to Java's serialization.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to you question, but it won't fit in a comment and I think it needs to be said.

**Be sure to reset your output stream after each write!**  ObjecdtOutputStream only writes an object once.  If you try to write it again, it will just send a little note "Put that object I sent a while ago in back the input stream again at this point."  Saves space, but if your object has changed, those changes won't get through.  Also, the original object sent is going to be kept in memory on both sides, killing your performance.  Reset clears everything out and gives you a fresh start.

Also, I'd use Externalizable rather than Serializable.  This gives you control over what is sent (though you have to write some code).  There is some danger that if you write an object that refers to other objects it will write all those other objects as well, which you may not want.  Also, Externalizable lets you write to the same, old format even if the class changes.  Also, it lets you put in version numbers.  These can sometimes allow a newer version to read a stream written by an older version, but it always gives you a warning that the format has changed.

The intent of ObjectOutputStream is that you can write one object that includes all your data.  A truly vast graph can be sent with one call to writeObject.  This is ingenious.  It worked fine for me, writing the complete state of a computer game to a disk file with one `writeObject( this )`, but it's usually a disaster when writing to a socket.

I am somewhat inclined not to use ObjectOutput, but to just write primitives.  It's simpler and faster and you have a lot of control.  But I have had trouble knowing which object to create on the Input end.  I think the best thing to do is read and write objects, but keep the I/O simple by writing your own method for the Externalizable interface and calling `reset()` after each `writeObject`.